# Sort child elements by date with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to sort some child elements of the div `#rgMatches` with the class `.GroupItem`. Some of these child elements contain a date and time as text. For instance `2022-09-24 16:45:00`. **Some child elements do not contain the date & time. They should not be sorted.**

With the following script it works fine. The newest item was placed at the first position. **Issue:** If I run the script for the second time it changes the sorting order. For instance, I have 4 items with a date. Running the script again the newest item gets position 4.

What's going wrong? Thank you for your hints

```js
function sortingContacts() {
  $('#rgMatches .rows .GroupItem').sort(function(a, b) {
    if ($(a).find('.creationDate').text() != '') {
      return new Date($(a).find('.creationDate').text()) < new Date($(b).find('.creationDate').text()) ? 1 : -1;
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }).appendTo('#rgMatches .rows');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rgMatches">
  <div class="rows">
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
        2022-09-24 16:10:00
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
        2022-09-24 16:05:23
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
        2022-09-24 16:05:22
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
        2022-09-24 16:05:27
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) Your `sort()` logic should always return a value, whether that's `1`, `0` or `-1`. 2) Can you please add the relevant HTML to the question so we can see a working example to recreate your specific use case 3) How are you expecting to sort ***some*** of the elements but not others? Either they are all sorted, or none of them are.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to sort all elements without a date to the bottom?

Comment: @pilchard no that works fine. I figured out that the issue only appears in a mobile browser...strange. It doesn't appear in common browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues in your code. Firstly, you need to check that the `.creationDate` element has content in both the `a` ***and*** `b` elements. Secondly you need to also return a value in the case where it doesn't, not just a plain `return;` statement. In the example below I used `0`, but this can be amended to `1` or `-1` as necessary for your use case.

Note in the example how clicking the 'Sort' button multiple times doesn't change the outcome.

```js
function sortingContacts() {
  $('#rgMatches .rows .GroupItem').sort((a, b) => {
    let aText = $(a).find('.creationDate').text();
    let bText = $(b).find('.creationDate').text();
    
    if (aText != '' && bText != '') {
      return new Date(aText) < new Date(bText) ? 1 : -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }).appendTo('#rgMatches .rows');
}

$('button').on('click', sortingContacts);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rgMatches">
  <div class="rows">
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
        2022-09-24 16:10:00
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
        2022-09-24 16:05:23
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
        2022-09-24 16:05:22
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
        2022-09-24 16:05:27
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button>Sort</button>
```

Comment: possibly better to `return new Date(aText) - new Date(bText);` to account for equal dates